# Laravel Routing - returning the correct view

Tags: url-routing, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to get into laravel and was just wondering about the routing.

Say if I were to create a website that sold cars, would I need to end up with routes like one for a manufacturer page, with a little overview of the history of Ford:
carshop.com/manufacturer/ford/
which would return a

and for browsing all the different SUVs:
carshop.com/cars/suv/

or is it possible use a controller to determine which model and view is required when the user navigates to either:
carshop.com/ford/
or
carshop.com/suv/

and still allows for static pages like:
carshop.com/contact-us/